# Deleting comments from program C#

Tags: c#, comments

So basically I need to remove comments from given file in `Duomenys.txt`

There are two types of comments:
1. // comments which should remove full line
2. /* TEXT */ comments that can go through multiple lines

I have wrote this piece of code but it does not fully work fine. Maybe does anyone would add some kind of improvement?

```
    static void Apdorojimas(out string[] visosEilutes)
    {
        visosEilutes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Duomenys.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        int visosEilutesKiekis = 0;
        bool RadauPradzia = false;
        foreach (string eilute in visosEilutes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < eilute.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != eilute.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (eilute[i] == '/' && eilute[i + 1] == '/')
                    {
                        visosEilutes[visosEilutesKiekis] = eilute.Remove(i, eilute.Length - i);
                    }
                    if (eilute[i] == '/' && eilute[i + 1] == '*')
                    {
                        RadauPradzia = true;
                    }
                    if (eilute[i] == '*' && eilute[i + 1] == '/')
                    {
                        RadauPradzia = false;
                    }
                }
                if (RadauPradzia)
                {
                    visosEilutes[visosEilutesKiekis] = visosEilutes[visosEilutesKiekis].Remove(i,1);
                }
            }
            visosEilutesKiekis++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to build a parse tree for this. because you might run into cases where the /* is inside a string and is actually not part of a comment. If you are not concerned about those you can do this easily with Regex

Comment: Let me know if Roslyn is absolutely off limits for some reason and I'll re-open.

Comment: Could I get an example? Never worked with Regex.